# Infinite printing in console when a function called inside map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I call a function from a map() it is causing infinite printing into the console. I want the app to call the function showImage(taskId) and if the status value equals the string "CREATED" then it should return the block of code inside it. If it doesn't match it should return the block of code inside else. Currently, I have two items in the database and it should be checked only twice, not infinite times.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TaskOneServices from '../services/TaskOneServices'
import circle from '../assets/icons/dry-clean.png'
import tick from '../assets/icons/check-mark.png'

export default class TaskListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            task_one:[],
            status: ""
        }

        this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this)
        // this.updateTask = this.updateTask.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        TaskOneServices.getTasks().then((response) => {
            this.setState({task_one: response.data})
        });
    }

    deleteTask = (id) => {
        
        JSON.stringify(id);
        TaskOneServices.deleteTask(id).then((response) => {
            this.refreshPage();
        });
    }
    
    refreshPage = () => {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    strikeThroughFn(taskid) {
        console.log(taskid);
        var fetchTask = document.getElementById('strikeTask');
        fetchTask.innerHTML = <strike> + {taskid} + </strike>
    }
    
    showImage (taskId)  {

        TaskOneServices.getStatus(taskId).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                status: response.data
            })
        });
        //causing infinite printing into console -- starts --
        console.log(this.state.status);
        //causing infinite printing into console -- ends --

        if(this.state.status === "CREATED") {
            return (
                <img className="img-lm" src={circle} alt="bullets" onClick={(e) => {this.taskCompleted(e, taskId)}}/>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <img className="img-lm" src={tick} alt="checked" onClick={(e) => {this.taskCompleted(e, taskId)}}/>
            )
        } 
    }

    taskCompleted(e, taskid) {
    if(e.target.getAttribute('src') === circle) {
        e.target.setAttribute( 'src', tick);
        e.target.setAttribute( 'alt', 'checked');
        this.updateTask(taskid);
    } else {
        e.target.setAttribute( 'src', circle);
        e.target.setAttribute( 'alt', 'bullets');
        this.updateTask(taskid);
    }
    }

    updateTask(id) {

        JSON.stringify(id);
        TaskOneServices.updateTask(id).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid bg-white">
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table border-bottom table-pad">
                        <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.task_one.map(
                                task =>
                                <tr key = {task.id}>
                                    <td width="60px">
                                     //check this part of code -- start --
                                       {this.showImage(task.id)}
                                     //check this part of code -- end --
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="strikeTask">{task.task}</td>
                                    <td width="60px">
                                        <button type="button" className="close text-danger btn-close-style" onClick={() => this.deleteTask(task.id)}>
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever the page is re-rendered `showImage` is called, inside of the function you are setting a state, which triggers another re-render, this is why you have an infinite loop, since `TaskOneService.getStatus` is called inside of `componentDidMount`, you can remove it from `showImage` and it should fix it

Comment: @sschwei1 TaskOneService.getTasks is called inside of componentDidMount. Can I also add TaskOneService.getStatus inside componentDidMount?

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see the different method names. And yes you even should do it, if you want to automatically update the status live on the page, you should either add a button which calls `TaskOneService.getStatus` and sets it to a new value, or create an interval which updates it all few seconds. Did I explain it clearly why you have an infinite loop here or should I try to explain it again?

Comment: @sschwei1 Thanks bro :)

Comment: is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by passing `task.id`, `task.task` and `task.status` as parameters in `showimage()` from inside the map(). Now the infinite looping is stopped and I can compare the `task.status` value with the string "CREATED".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TaskOneServices from '../services/TaskOneServices'
import circle from '../assets/icons/dry-clean.png'
import tick from '../assets/icons/check-mark.png'

export default class TaskListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            task_one:[],
        }

        this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(taskId) {
        TaskOneServices.getTasks().then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                task_one: response.data
            })
        });

    }

    deleteTask = (id) => {
        
        JSON.stringify(id);
        TaskOneServices.deleteTask(id).then((response) => {
            this.refreshPage();
        });
    }
    
    refreshPage = () => {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    showImage (taskStatus, taskId, taskString)  {

        if(taskStatus === "CREATED") {
            return (
                <div>
                    <img className="img-lm" src={circle} alt="bullets" onClick={(e) => {this.taskCompleted(e, taskId)}}/>
                    <span className="span-style">{taskString}</span>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <img className="img-lm" src={tick} alt="checked" onClick={(e) => {this.taskCompleted(e, taskId)}}/>
                    <span className="span-style"><strike>{taskString}</strike></span>
                </div>

            )
        }
    }

    taskCompleted(e, taskid) {
    if(e.target.getAttribute('src') === circle) {
        e.target.setAttribute( 'src', tick);
        e.target.setAttribute( 'alt', 'checked');
        this.updateTask(taskid);
    } else {
        e.target.setAttribute( 'src', circle);
        e.target.setAttribute( 'alt', 'bullets');
        this.updateTask(taskid);
    }
    }

    updateTask(id) {

        JSON.stringify(id);
        TaskOneServices.updateTask(id).then((response) => {
            this.refreshPage();
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid bg-white">
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table border-bottom">
                        <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.task_one.map(
                                task =>
                                <tr key = {task.id}>
                                    <td width="60px">
                                         {this.showImage(task.status, task.id, task.task)}
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="60px">
                                        <button type="button" className="close text-danger btn-close-style" onClick={() => this.deleteTask(task.id)}>
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```